# What does schizo mean in “schizophrenia” and “schizo tech”?

Tags: meaning, etymology, abbreviations, pop-culture

TV Tropes says that the [Naruto universe](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/SchizoTech/AnimeAndManga) lives in Schizo Tech.

> The universe essentially mixes feudal society with modern technology (and clothing). The only exceptions are things like cars and guns. The only fields of technology which are outdated are transportation and military.

It also goes on to explain that [**Schizo Tech**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SchizoTech) is

> The setting and timeline may seem at first to be The Middle Ages, The Colonial Period, or some Fantasy Counterpart Culture thereof, but when you look closer, you find polyester, robots, or other high-tech toys in between the horse-drawn wagons and wattle-and-daub buildings. There's generally no rhyme or reason for which technologies are anachronistically present besides the Rule of Cool.

So some technology exists while others do not.

- What does the term *schizo* mean? It's in *schizophrenia* and *Schizo Tech*

I think it's Latin or Greek but I don't know where else should I ask this.

After all, isn't *schizophrenia* an English word?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Schizophrenia" comes from Ancient Greek σχίζω (skhízō, “to split”) + φρήν (phrḗn, “mind, heart, diaphragm”).

(source: [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schizophrenia))

"schizo tech" is a reference to schizophrenia. Just like in schizophrenia, multiple personalities can appear in the same person, schizo tech refers to fiction where technologies from multiple eras appear at the same time.

Comment: I thought schizoprenia means someone that "seeing things". People like self proclaimed prophets.

Comment: @J.Chang the term is spelled with two "h's" it's [schiz•o•PHRE•ni•a](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4JnF-XDx9g)

Answer (score 1):

From the Online Etymology Dictionary's entry for [**schizophrenia**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/schizophrenia#etymonline_v_22884):

> 1912, from Modern Latin, literally "a splitting of the mind," from German Schizophrenie, coined in 1910 by Swiss psychiatrist Eugen Bleuler (1857-1939), from Greek skhizein "to split" (from PIE root [*skei](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*skei-?ref=etymonline_crossreference)- "to cut, split") + phren (genitive phrenos) "heart, mind" (hence phrenes "wits, sanity"); see [phreno-](https://www.etymonline.com/word/phreno-?ref=etymonline_crossreference).

Although it seems there are multiple backgrounds for *schizophrenia* itself, you're most likely interested in the Greek *skhizein*.

Note that Merriam-Webster defines the *English* word [*schizo*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schizo) simply as a synonym for "a schizophrenic individual."

Comment: Yes. Meriam Webster is very unclear.